# No bouncing effect with animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion: method

Tags: ios4, uiviewanimation

When I write my animation code within beginAnimation-commitAnimatin blocks I get a bouncing effect, however I don't get the same effect when I do the same animation with the method written in the subject. Here are two ways to do what I want:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];

[UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:2];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:
@selector(resetTheChickenProperties)];

theChicken.frame = CGRectMake(15, 330, 62, 90);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

the way shown above the image (it's an egg) goes down in the y direction until it hits the ground and bounces back. Bouncing effect is clearly observed. But if I do the same thing with the help of the animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:compeletion method the egg does not bounce. It rather seems like hung on a spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've found the subtle detail everyone needs to take note of in order to get the animation and transitions work with the method available in iOS 4 and later.When specifying the animation/transition options for the method we must use the constants with the word "Option" in it. So instead of writing

```
UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn|UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp
```

we should write

```
UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn|UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
```

after fixing that the animation worked just fine. I was able to get the real bouncing effect